# Accessing Data from a internal class in windows form

Tags: c#

I am trying to access the dcam in the internal class. The initialization process starts when it starts.

```
    internal class Ham4MPBase : CameraBase, IDisposable
    {
        private bool sf;
        private Dcam dcam;

        public bool Initialize()
        {
            sf = DcamApi.init();
            if (sf)
            {
                Dcam aDcam = new Dcam();
                if (!aDcam.dev_open(0))
                {
                    aDcam = null;
                    MessageBox.Show("Camera init/open failed");
                }
                dcam = aDcam;
                MessageBox.Show("Camera init/open success");

                _initialized = true;
                return _initialized;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Camera init failed");
            }
        }

    }
```

Here, I have data inside of dcam.
Now imagine that I have a button in another namespace where after pressing it would start to acquire image, like below:

```
   public partial class CameraControlPanel : UserControl
   {
        private Dcam dcam;

        private void buttonImageAquire_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dcam == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Internal Error: dcam is null");
                return;                                  // internal error
            }
            string text = "";

            //Start acquisition
            m_cap_stopping = false;
            dcam.m_capmode = DCAMCAP_START.SEQUENCE;   //Continuous Acquisiton
// ....
```

I am stuck here because dcam shows to be null. How can I expose data from this internal class into my form?

Comment: How is `Dcam`, `MyDcam`  and `Ham4MPBase` related?

Comment: It should be public, if you want it exposed to other classes.

Comment: My apologies, I have corrected the typos. I've instantiated the camera object in the internal class Ham4MPBase, but I need to be able to call it in the form CameraControlPanel.

Comment: @ChesterAyala I make it public from internal, but the issue persists where dcam = null on the CameraControlPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose a property to the user control to set the dcam

```
public partial class CameraControlPanel : UserControl
{
    private Dcam mydcam;

    public Dcam Camera { get => mydcam; set => mydcam = value; }

}
```

and then in the form where the control is initialized

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    protected override OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        cameraControlPanel1.Camera = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what OnLoad is for as well as what should come after cameraControlPanel1.Camera?

Comment: @lishiyu - that information is missing from the question. You have not specified how the dcam is initialized. I used the `OnLoad()` override which gets called before the form is shown, but you can choose how or when to assign the `.Camera` property.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to Pass the data through with the following:
'public Dcam cameraa { get => Ham4MPBase.Cameraa; set => cameraa = value; }' as well as the OnLoad() override.